# Flag quantity refilling?

Tags: support, flags

I just flagged, for the first time, a recent question as an advert.

I noticed that, when I did, it said that I had 9 flags left.

Could someone explain to me or point me to info about how flags work and at what rate they replenish?

I did read a few other questions but didn't really see anything that covered this.

I don't expect to flag very often, just curious about the mechanics.

Thanks!

Comment: I think they refill daily. I think the more rep you have the more you get per day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Flags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) are rate-limited so you only flag *important* issues and don't flood moderators and review queues alike with mundane problems.

The amount of flags you get depends primarily on *reputation* and *helpful flag count*:

> **How many flags do I have?**
>   When you start out, you are allotted **10** flags per day. This number may increase to up to **100** flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).

Flag limits, like most other metrics on the site, reset at midnight UTC.

Comment: Thanks!  This is very helpful.  I appreciate it.